# Create a new process in current console window

Tags: java, console, window, build-process

I have a Java application which for example needs to restart itself (but also needs to start other processes). This is currently done by closing the current application and then start a new instance using a ShutdownHook and a ProcessBuilder.

My problem is now that the new process runs somewhere in the background and does not have its own console window. On windows machines, a new console window can be created using

```
cmd /c start "windowtitle" java -jar myApp.jar
```

But this creates 2 processes: the cmd process and the java process started by 'start'. This makes it for example impossible to get the stdout and stderr of the started process, because we only get those streams for the cmd process, not for the one started by the 'start' command.

The very best solution for me would be to reuse the current console window for the new process but this seems somehow impossible to achieve as i did not find any information on how to do this.
Additionally I would appreciate a solution which works on Unix machines.

Answer (score 0):

Seems, you owe to use small **console** program-starter for java. It must start java and immediately exit.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  STARTUPINFO si = {sizeof(si)};
  PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = {};
  CreateProcess(NULL,_T("java -jar myApp.jar"),0,0,0,NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,0,0,&si,&pi);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if that's what you're looking for, but it might help.

```
List<String> command = Arrays.asList("java", "-jar", "myApp.jar");
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process process = builder.start();

InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
final InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

String line = null;
while ((line = br.getLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println("child process: " + line);
}

process.waitFor();
```

The `builder.redirectErrorStream(true);` will redirect the stderr to stdout and the while loop will write the stdout of the child process to the stdout of your main application. And don't forget to `try catch` the `Streams` and `Buffers`